# I have problem when I implemented this command sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I have problem when I implemented this command

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
```

And I get this:

```
fawaz@fawaz-Lenovo-B590:~$ sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tcl8.5-dev : Depends: tcl8.5 (= 8.5.11-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 tk8.5-dev : Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libxss-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libxext-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libxft-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: tk8.5 (= 8.5.11-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
fawaz@fawaz-Lenovo-B590:~$
```

PLZ help me

Comment: That version of Ubuntu? How is composed the file /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: You may find your answer most likely here
 http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following commands into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then enter:

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.5 libx11-dev libxss-dev libxext-dev libxft-dev tk8.5.11-1
```

Now try installing `tcl8.5-dev` and `tk8.5-dev` again:

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
```